allowEmptyValue in an OpenAPI 3.0 form parameter?
Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 had in: formData, which was supposedly superseded by contentBody in 3.0, where every such parameter becomes a Schema Object inside a Media Type Object. However, JSON Schema doesn't seem to define allowEmptyValue (or an equivalent).
Hence my question:
How do I specify a form parameter that can have an empty value in OpenAPI 3.0?
P.S. Here's a real-life example as 2.0:
swagger: 2.0
info:
  title: Brick Owl
  version: v1
paths:
  /collection/update:
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: lot_id
          in: formData
          required: true
        - name: quantity
          in: formData
        - name: price
          in: formData
          type: number
          allowEmptyValue: true

Which in 3.1.0 becomes:

openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: Brick Owl
  version: v1
paths:
  /collection/update:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              properties:
                lot_id: {}
                quantity: {}
                price:
                  type: number
              required:
              - lot_id

The property of price is lost in translation.
P.P.S. According to the spec, I am allowed to add an allowEmptyValue property as an extension to the Schema Object, but that looks like kludge to me.

All fields in a reference schema are optional by default unless explicitly specified as required.

@J.Titus An optional parameter isn't the same as a parameter with an empty value. In my case, an update operation accepts an optional price parameter, of which an empty value means the price is to be cleared at the backend (as opposed to no change to the price in the case of no price parameter being passed).

Sounds like you want "type":["null", "number"]
